# how to solve multiple `get_dispatch_info` found error?

Tags: pallet, substrate-node-template, error, releases

[image]

I'm using get_dispatch_info() function.earlier it's working fine but after new release I'm not able to use it.

```
let dispatch_info = call.get_dispatch_info();
    dispatch_info.weight.saturating_add(10_000), dispatch_info.class, Pays::Yes)
        })]
```

I'm getting this error :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remove one of your `GetDispatchInfo` imports, or specify which trait you are calling.

Instead of `call.get_dispatch_info();` you can do `frame_support::dispatch::GetDispatchInfo::get_dispatch_info(&call);`

But the correct solution is to fix your imports so that there is no conflict.